# An error : Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I am getting the error-msg when i try the following code:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ServerName].[dbo].[TableName1] B 
 WHERE right(B.TableName1, 2) = '34' AND 
 B.UnitId=
 (select distinct D.UnitId 
 from [ServerName].[dbo].[TableName2] D
 INNER JOIN @temp E ON D.UnitId=E.UnitId)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? It says the subquery returned more than 1 value. The temp-table is created and contains a selection of the number individuals that I want to count, by unitId.

Comment: I'd suggest possibly changing ` B.UnitId=` to `B.UnitId IN` then your select statement.  Your subquery in the `WHERE` clause is most likely returning multiple rows and `B.UnitId` can't be equal to more than one row at a time.

Comment: I made a few edits to my answer, should speed up the query by a fraction.  Please consider upvoting and marking answers (check box below the vote) for the posts that you find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a join instead of the subquery:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    [ServerName].[dbo].[TableName1] B
INNER JOIN [ServerName].[dbo].[TableName2] D ON B.UnitId = D.UnitId
INNER JOIN @temp E ON D.UnitId = E.UnitId
WHERE   RIGHT(B.TableName1, 2) = '34'
```

Comment: it looks strange but conceptually inner joins are better then sub queries .. i know sql server is smart and can chnge sub query in to joins at compile time but still joins are better

Answer (score 0):

The subquery (`select distinct`) has more than one value returned.  As such `B.UnitId` cannot *equal* more than one value.

You can use `IN` if its ok for `B.UnitId` to have more than one value.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [ServerName].[dbo].[TableName1] B 
WHERE right(B.TableName1, 2) = '34' 
AND B.UnitId in (select D.UnitId 
                 from [ServerName].[dbo].[TableName2] D
                 INNER JOIN @temp E ON D.UnitId=E.UnitId)
```

`Distinct` becomes superfluous when you use `IN`.